# Store gnome keyring on a flash-drive?

Tags: gnome-keyring

I was wondering - is there a way to store my gnome key-ring on a usb drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. It's a [Gnome Keyring Goal](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Goals) though:

> Storage of Keys and Certificates on Removable Media
>
> Build a PKCS#11 module which allows storage of keys, certificates, and
>   passwords on removable media. This can be used as a poor man's smart
>   card, or for mobility.
>
> - Task: Not yet implemented.

Comment: that would have been awesome.